# Matlab simplification by combining expressions to symbols

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Can someone help my how to simplify a symbolic expression in matlab by replacing specific terms with a symbol. For example if I have the function `f = 1/2*m1*(x^2+y^2) + m2*(x^2+y^2);`  I want tosimplify the expression by combining `m=m1+2*m2` such that the equation becomes `f = 1/2*m(x^2+y^2)`

is this possible to do automatically in matlab for more complicated expressions? or do I have to do this manually?

So far I have tried using the subs function, the assume function and the replace function:

`subs(f,m1+2*mc,m)` this does not do anything

`assume(m1+2*m2 == m)` This does not do anything

`replace(f,m1+2*m2,m)` This do not work unless it is text

Furthermore I have tried to use the subs function in reverse:

`subs(K_tot, [m1, m2], [m-2*m2, m2]);`

Hope someone is able to help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

substituting `m1` to remove it from the equation will work if you later simplify the resulting expression.

```matlab
syms m1 m2 x y m;

f = 1/2*m1*(x^2+y^2) + m2*(x^2+y^2);

f2 = subs(f, m1, m-2*m2);

f3 = simplify(f2);
display(f3)
```

```
f3 =
 
(m*(x^2 + y^2))/2
```

you can increase the `Steps` in the [simplify](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html) arguments if you are sure the simplification is possible.

Comment: Hmm I see this works for this equation... but if I want to do it for more complex equation I cannot get that to function

Comment: @KSH you can consider increasing the `Steps` in the [simplify](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html) arguments if you are sure the simplification is possible.